# Connect Oracle Java Stored Procedure to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, stored-procedures

So I am building a java stored procedure on an Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition. I want my Java stored procedure to connect to a MySQL database, grab records and update my Oracle database. I can connect using

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    // Create an OracleDataSource instance and set properties
    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setUser(user);
    ods.setPassword(passwd);
    ods.setURL(url);
    return ods.getConnection();
}
```

I am connecting using the following lib which works fine

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
```

But when I try to open a connection to a MySQL database in the Java stored procedure I get the following error

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
ORA-06512: at "OPS.FN_JOB_UPDATE_ORACLE_LINE", line 1
ORA-06512: at "OPS.JOBS_PKG", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I am assuming it has something to do the MySQL driver not being in the classpath on the Oracle server itself but I am not sure how to get it within the classpath.

Here is an example of how I am trying to connect to the MySQL database from the java stored procedure

```
public Connection setMysqlConnection(EntityDBSettings entity) throws 
SQLException {
    String connectionStr = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s/%s?user=%s&password=%s", entity.getHost_uri(),
            entity.getName(), entity.getUsername(), entity.getPaswrd());

    this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStr);
    return this.connect;
}
```

So is it possiable to connect to a MySql database from a oracle java stored procedure? Or do I need another solution?

Comment: The database needs all the classes in the MySQL JDBC jar file, so you need to load them into the database. E.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b12021/appover.htm#1006331

Comment: same error after loading the jar and all its .class files. Looks like I need a way to include the jar into the classpath.